# Async/Await with Vuex dispatch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuex

I am making a loader for some components in my app.

Here is my component:

```
        mounted() {
            this.loading = true;

            this.getProduct();
        },
        methods: {
            async getProduct() {
                await this.$store.dispatch('product/getProducts', 'bestseller');

                console.log(123);

                this.loading = false;
            }
        },
```

Vuex action:

```
getProducts({commit}, type) {
        axios.get(`/api/products/${type}`)
            .then(res => {
                let products = res.data;
                commit('SET_PRODUCTS', {products, type})
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    },
```

The problem is in this line: `await this.$store.dispatch('product/getProducts', 'bestseller');`

I expect the code will stop at that line and wait for data is loaded from AJAX call and then set the loading is `false`;

But it isn't. The loading is still set `false` and the `console.log` run before my data is ready.

I already tried to move async/await into Vuex action and it worked. However, I didn't get the difference between them.

Below code is worked for me:

Component:

```
mounted() {
            this.loading = true;

            this.$store.dispatch('product/getProducts', 'bestseller').then((res) => {
                this.loading = false;
            });
        },
```

Vuex action:

```
async getProducts({commit}, type) {
        let res = await axios.get(`/api/products/${type}`);

        commit('SET_PRODUCTS', {products: res.data, type});
    }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Change this:

```
getProducts({commit}, type) {
    axios.get(`/api/products/${type}`)
        .then(res => {
            let products = res.data;
            commit('SET_PRODUCTS', {products, type})
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
},
```

To this:

```
getProducts({commit}, type) {
    return axios.get(`/api/products/${type}`)
        .then(res => {
            let products = res.data;
            commit('SET_PRODUCTS', {products, type})
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
},
```

Should work.

`axios.get` returns a promise. You would need to return that promise in order to let `await` wait for it. Otherwise, you are implicitly returning `undefined` and `await undefined` would immediately resolve.

Comment: "you are implicitly returning undefined and await undefined would immediately resolve" This helped for my case.Thanks !

Comment: totally forgot to return the axios promise, life saver!

Comment: woooo im glad to find this solution, thank you so so much!

Answer (score 7):

You can not await a function without promise

```
await this.$store.dispatch('product/getProducts', 'bestseller');
```

This function return data or call new action

```
getProducts({commit}, type) {
    axios.get(`/api/products/${type}`)
        .then(res => {
            let products = res.data;
            commit('SET_PRODUCTS', {products, type})
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
},
```

And this function return promise because of async function

```
async function return promise

async getProducts({commit}, type) {
    let res = await axios.get(`/api/products/${type}`);

    commit('SET_PRODUCTS', {products: res.data, type});

}
```

Now using above function now you can use

```
await this.$store.dispatch('product/getProducts', 'bestseller');
```

with await key word
Or you can return axios because axios also return a promise.