# Retrieve Data from Vuex Store using Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I've been searching around for possible answers to my question but I couldn't find anymore suggestions.

The structure of my project is as follows. I have a PoolMainPage where I show some information of the `activePool` Object. Within the `PoolMainPage` there are options to direct to subpages (`TeamSelector` and `PoolStandings`), which also require information of the `activePool`Object.

The activePool Object is fetched from an endpoint in the Vuex store. The code for that is the following:

```
const actions = {  
  getActivePool({ commit }) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      withCredentials: true
    }
    const activePoolId = localStorage.getItem('activePoolId')
    if (activePoolId) {
      return axios.get('/pools/pool-information?poolId=' + activePoolId, config)
        .then((response) => {
          commit('SET_ACTIVE_POOL', response.data)
          return response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return Promise.reject(error)
        })
    } else {
      commit('SET_ACTIVE_POOL', null);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

The endpoint does it's job and returns the `activePool` object. In my `PoolMainPage` component (as well as in the subcomponents) I want to call this action and fetch the object, using:

```
created() {
    if (!this.$store.getters.activePool) {
      this.$store.dispatch("getActivePool");
    }
  },
```

I added the check to prevent that the endpoint is called everytime the page is refreshed and the `activePool` is already set. To actually load the `activePool` into the component, I created a computed property:

```
computed: {
    activePool() {
      return this.$store.getters.activePool;
    },
  },
```

This all works when the endpoint has returned its data, but before that I receive an error on another computed property, which is dependent on the `activePool` object:

```
maxToSpend() {
      return this.activePool.inGameBudget;
    },
```

Question 1: how do I make sure that `maxToSpend` does not compute until the `activePool` actually set? I can simply add an additional check `if (this.activePool) {`, but then I would have to do that for all of the computed properties.

Question 2: I don't know if this is possible, but how do make sure that I don't have to add the code to fetch the `activePool` from the endpoint and get it using the computed property within each of the components that I created: `TeamSelector` and `PoolStandings`?

All help/suggestions are appreciated! Let me know if anything is unclear or requires some additional information.

Thanks!

Jeroen

Comment: for question1 you should look into async/await

Comment: Thanks @Asadali, I looked into it and created an `async` function and awaited the result with `await`, but no luck. Also looked at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700815/async-await-with-vuex-dispatch/55701072, but I still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make sure that maxToSpend does not compute until the activePool actually set?

Basically you cannot do that. The computed properties are compute right after component create. See [Lifecycle Diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), computed properties are compute at Init injections & reactivity state.

> I can simply add an additional check if (this.activePool) {, but then I would have to do that for all of the computed properties.

You case use [Getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html):

```js
state: {
  ...
},
getters: {
  maxToSpend: state => {
    if (!state.activePool) return
    return state.activePool.inGameBudget
  }
},
actions: {
  ...
}
```

Then you can use as:

```js
computed: {
  maxToSpend () {
    return this.$store.getters.maxToSpend
  }
}
```

> I don't know if this is possible, but how do make sure that I don't have to add the code to fetch the activePool from the endpoint and get it using the computed property within each of the components that I created: TeamSelector and PoolStandings?

Basically no. But if both TeamSelector and PoolStandings have common a parent (might be PoolMainPage?) then you can call it only once from that parent.

In my opinion the way to explicitly dispatch mandatory action for every page its needed it's not a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you very much! The explanation is really clear and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can mount activePool getter to avoid errors when accessing nested properties. Like:

```js
// in getters.js

const activePool = (state) => ({
  ...state.activePool,
  maxToSpend: state.activePool && state.activePool.inGameBudget,
})
```

activePool.inGameBudget will always be there, regardless the Promise. So now you can access `this.activePool.inGameBudget;` in `.vue` file and you wont get the error.